# How to track error, count it and send it to Google Analytics

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor

I've an interceptor that redirects to route `/page-error` on every api error

```
    return next.handle(request.clone()).pipe(
      catchError((err: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/page-error']);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    )
```

AppComponent for tracking the `page-error`

```
    router.events.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged((previous: any, current: any) => {
        if (current instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          return previous.url === current.url;
        }
        return true;
      }),
      filter(current => current.url === '/page-error')
    )
    .subscribe((current: any) => {
      //count as error and send it to GA
    });
```

I want to count how many times the page error was landed if an API error occurs.

But I've got a problem, for example:

User is currently in the home page (no API error occurs here) and then go back to the previous page (it's the error page), it's counting as an error. This scenario also occurs when the next page was the error page;

There's a way to prevent to not count as error in these scenarios?

Comment: You can add ga code before this.router.navigate(['/page-error']); This way you only run it when the error was caught.

Comment: Shouldn't you just skip that page to end up in the history? See `skipLocationChange` here https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationBehaviorOptions. This way it wouldn't be possible to go back or next to that page

Comment: @maxime1992 Your approach really work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make use of Angular's NavigationExtras which allows you to pass additional information during routing. Here's what you can do:

```
return next.handle(request.clone()).pipe(
  catchError((err: any) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/page-error'], { state: { fromInterceptor: true } });
    return throwError(err);
  })
)
```

AppComponent

```
router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map(() => this.router.getCurrentNavigation()),
  filter(navigation => {
    return navigation && navigation.extras && navigation.extras.state && navigation.extras.state.fromInterceptor;
  }),
  filter(current => current.finalUrl && current.finalUrl.toString() === '/page-error')
)
.subscribe((current: any) => {
  // count as error and send it to GA
});
```

Comment: I'm still having problems in these scenarios: User is currently in the home page (no API error occurs here) and then go back to the previous page (it's the error page), it's counting as an error and. This scenario also occurs when the next page was the error page;